# Error: "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard"

Tags: ios, swift

on this line of code:

```
if diceRoll == userGuessTextField.text {
```

I get this error:

```
2016-02-04 18:38:34.756 How Many Fingers[2972:158461] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userGuessTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var resultLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func guess(sender: AnyObject) {

    let diceRoll = String(arc4random_uniform(6))


        if diceRoll == userGuessTextField.text {


            resultLabel.text = "You're right!"
        }
        else {

            resultLabel.text = "Wrong! It was a " + diceRoll
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Your @IBOutlet var userGuessTextField: UITextField! is not hooked up to a textField in IB. Drag from the empty gray circle next to it to the textField you want to be userGuessTextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a warning that the keyboard type doesn't exist, most likely deprecated.

> ```
> 2016-02-04 18:38:34.756 How Many Fingers[2972:158461] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 1336863583_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
> ```

This on the other hand is an error that is most likely due the fact that `userGuessTextField.text` is `nil` and can't be compared.

> ```
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
> (lldb)
> ```

The solution for you here would be to check that `userGuessTextField.text` has a value, and as **beyowulf** suggested, you should connect the `userGuessTextField` to its storyboard element.